# Storing a key-string value securely

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I need to keep safe a key-string value (generated inside my app) on the device in a secure manner so that it cannot be accessed by unauthorized users or any other universal apps. This key value is used for making a reference to a table (inside OS) and I need to protect this key completely.

Answer (score 2):

I think this API would help you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker